# Ubuntu 12.04 swap USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb, swap

I'm new in ubuntu and I tried to install the alternate CD in my machine. Everything went fine but when I tried to boot a black screen and a blink cursor went on. I can boot from my USB and searching in internet I found a post suggesting that the swap was into the USB, the suggestion is to reinstall ubuntu. My question is: is there a way to fix this (booting from the hdd of my computer) without reinstalling?

If not, what should I do different in the new installation in order to avoid this situation in the future?

I hope you could give me a hand with this.
Best regards,
Seba.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue - the computer was trying to boot off the wrong drive.

Unplug any USB drives or other drives apart from the drive you want to boot from, then check in BIOS that it is selecting the right drive to boot from (especially if you have multiple internal drives).